# Eclipse gdb error while Stepping Over

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I'm new to C and while debugging a simple file IO code snippet, the Eclipse debugger (using gdb) gave the following error:

`Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/libio/iofgets.c"`

`Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.`

THe line where the debugger crashes is

```
while (NULL!=fgets(line, SIZE, fp))
```

It looks like the debugger is looking for the source code for fgets in the folder `build/buildd/.../libio/`, but I'm not trying to step into this line, I'm stepping over it.

I'm using eclipse version 3.8 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: " the debugger crashes" - it doesn't. Try to "step out". check if you have accidentally added some breakpoints in the disassembly..

Comment: Hi - I only have one breakpoint set in the entire project. Also the "step out" button (F7) is disabled

Comment: Can you open gdb console (in eclipse) and manually try "info break" and "next" commands when you are on that line. What does gdb say?

Comment: @dbrank0 - thanks! your comment provided the hint. The program was actually crashing at line 50 of `iofgets.c`. After a little investigation, it turns out my function pointer fp was NULL. I definitely need practice with C and gdb!